# How to call Java method on patricular interval of time which is deployed to Apache Tomcat server as a web application?

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, struts2, scheduled-tasks

I'm developing an web application which is developed in Struts 2 and I'm deploying it on Apache Tomcat server.

I want to do database cleanup on daily basis automatically.

Also I want to to call a method in java class with 10 minutes of interval. Any suggestion for this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Quartz scheduler with Struts2 or Spring's `@Scheduled`. Here's the example to use [Struts 2 + Spring 3 + Quartz 1.8 Scheduler Example](http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-spring-3-quartz-1-8-scheduler-example/).

There you can modify cron expression to run every 10 min

```xml
<property name="cronExpression" value="* 0/10 * * * ?" />
```

Answer (score 0):

## `ScheduledExecutorService`

This topic has been addressed many times already on a Stack Overflow.

[Learn about executors](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/executors.html).

Specifically look at [`ScheduledExecutorService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html).

A background thread can run your task at regular intervals.